# Merging the contents of my array into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of several objects

```
array1 =[ {1:Eat},{2:Shower},{3:Shave}]
```

I want to convert this array into a single object

```
object1 ={1:Eat, 2:Shower, 3:Shave}
```

How do I go about it. The keys(1,2,3) are unique

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...array1)`

Comment: It is important to understand that the values for the keys of each of your objects inside the array need to be quoted to become a string.  I guess anyone's answer here is assuming that. Otherwise you will get a ReferenceError if those variables aren't defined an assigned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION**

`array.reduce((a, v) => Object.assign(a,v), {})`

**THE EXPLANATION**

Array.reduce() loops throw the initial array aimed to "reduce" it into a single object. The reduce method allows you to store the return value of each of your iterations. It requires an initial value which in this case it will be the empty object {} that we will be filling up with our array.

Then we use Object.assign(target, source) which concatenates two objects together returning the concatenated object which in this case it will saved into our accumulator and be used as a target for the next iteration giving you when it finishes the constructed final object. As you have objects as the keys of the array, each single property Object(source) will be "assigned" to a master one (target) that will be collecting all of them into one.

```js
array1 =[ {1:'Eat'},{2:'Shower'},{3:'Shave'}]
obj1 = array1.reduce((a, v) => Object.assign(a,v), {})
console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to reduce the list of objects into a single object.

```js
const
  input = [{ 1: 'Eat' }, { 2: 'Shower' }, { 3: 'Shave' }],
  output = input.reduce((acc, obj) => ({ ...acc, ...obj }), {});

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

fromEntries and a flatMap seems to do the trick nicely

```js
const array1 = [ {1:'Eat'},{2:'Shower'},{3:'Shave'}]
const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(array1.flatMap(item => Object.entries(item)))

console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop through the array and each object within it and add it to a master object as shown below.

```js
const array1 =[{ 1: 'Eat' }, { 2: 'Shower' }, { 3: 'Shave' }];
const masterObj = {};

array1.forEach(obj => { 
 for (const property in obj) {
  masterObj[property] = obj[property];
 };
});

console.log(masterObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my method of using `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` is the most efficient method, but it's something to get you started:

```js
array1 = [{
  1: "Eat"
}, {
  2: "Shower"
}, {
  3: "Shave"
}];

object1 = {};

array1.forEach(v => {
  object1[Object.keys(v)[0]] = Object.values(v)[0];
});

console.log(object1);
```